# merging rows from two files and writing to first file

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files file1.txt (larger) and file2.txt (smaller) and  I wanted to merge the contents of the second file into the first one only if the new rows are not duplicate.

I used this command

```
sudo sh -c "sort -u test_1.txt test_2.txt > test_3.txt ; mv test_3.txt test_1.txt"
```

I was just wondering if this is a scalable way to do it especially if I have more than two files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your files `file1.txt` ... `filen.txt` are already sorted, you can do a merge sort:

```
sort -m -u file1.txt ... filen.txt
```

This will be for sure the fastest. If your files are not sorted, then you can just do it without the merge flag:

```
sort -u file1.txt ... filen.txt
```

If you do not care about any form of sorting, you can use this [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) line:

```
awk '!($0 in a){a[$0]; print}' file1.txt ... filen.txt
```

Comment: Can I write everything to file1.txt?

Comment: @vkaul11 no, you have to send it to a temporary file and move it afterwards to the filename you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort and uniq if you don't care about maintaining the order of lines.

`sort file1 file2 [file3...filen] |  uniq > newfile.txt`